# Simplificacion de codigo para campos vacios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, condiciones, switch

Tengo un formulario en mi pagina donde tengo multiples campos y a cada uno, uno por uno valido si el campo esta vacio pero hay ocasiones donde debo validar 10 campos y mi codigo se extiende mucho, hay alguna manera de simplificar todo este codigo ?

```
if(negocioName == '' || negocioName == null){
        setErrorT1(true)
        toast.error('Nombre de unidad de negocio vacío', {
            position: "top-right",
            autoClose: 2000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            });
            setActive(false)
    return;
    } else {setErrorT1(false)}

    if(location == null || location == ''){
        setErrorT3(true)
        toast.error('Debes seleccionar una ubiación', {
            position: "top-right",
            autoClose: 2000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            });
            setActive(false)
    return;
    }else {setErrorT3(false)}
    if(logo == null || logo == ''){
        toast.error('Debes seleccionar una imagen', {
            position: "top-right",
            autoClose: 2000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            });
            setActive(false)
    return;
    }
```

por cada campo vacio yo mando un toast con un mensaje de campo vacio

Comment: Has intentado meter tus validaciones dentro de un método? Y solo estar llamando al método y este te devuelva `True` o `False`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una funcion para comprobar si se encuentra vacio un campo :

```
function validar(campo){
    if(campo == null || campo == undefined || campo == ""){
        //si esta indefinido el valor ejecuta el toast
    }
}
```

Ya luego es solo usarla con tus campos:

```
validar(negocioName);
validar(location);
```

Esto te ahorrara un poco de trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

podrias crear un custom hoock y solo validarlo en el formulario, si algun campo esta vacio lanzar una alerta:

custom hook para campos de texto

```
const { useState } = require("react")

const useField = (type) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  
    const onChange = (event) => {
      setValue(event.target.value)
    }
  
    return {
      type,
      value,
      onChange
    }
  }

export default useField
```

para usarlo en tu formulario solo llamas el hook cuantas veces lo necesites:

```
const userName = useField('text')
const userPassword = useField('password')
```

y en el submit del formulario podrias evaluar si el campo esta vacio

```
if(userName.value === '' || userPassword.value === ''){
      return alert('alert!')
  }
```

para mostrar el error puedes crear un componente y con props le pasas la informacion que quieres que muestre, asi no lo escribes cada vez que tienes un error